# How to print 2D array as a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++03

So I'm trying to store sentences in an array and then pass them to a vector and consequently print to screen such as:

```
void opt(char **desc)
{
      std::vector <std::string> desc_v(desc, desc + sizeof(desc)/sizeof(desc[0]));

      for (int i=0; i<desc_v.size(); ++i){
            std::cout<< desc_v[i]<<'\n';
      }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    static char *desc[] = {
    "This is an entire sentence",
    "And i want to keep printing the rest of the sentences"
    };

    opt(desc);
    return 0;
    }
```

**but it only prints:**

> This is an entire sentence

**Any help?
note: no c++11 please.**

Comment: Explain what you think `sizeof(desc)/sizeof(desc[0])` is doing and how it should work?   To fix this change that expression to `2` or however many sentences you have in your array.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `sizeof(desc)` and `sizeof(desc[0])`?

Comment: Any options for let's say the case where I don’t want to count the number of entries in desc?

Comment: There is no 2D array!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to let the `opt` function know how many strings are in the array.  A simple way to do this is to have the array size be a template parameter, and pass the array by reference. Here is a solution using `std::array`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<size_t N>
void opt(std::array<std::string, N> &desc)
{
    std::vector <std::string> desc_v( std::begin(desc), std::end(desc) );

    for ( auto&& s : desc_v )    // or just desc
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, 2> desc = {
        "This is an entire sentence",
        "And i want to keep printing the rest of the sentences"
    };

    opt(desc);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, `desc_v` is redundant, you could have just printed `desc`.

Alternatively, the function could be:

```
template<size_t N>
void opt(char const * const (&desc)[N])
```

with the same body, and you declare `desc` as:

```
char const *const desc[] = {
```

Your existing code was illegal since C++11 (and deprecated before that); string literals may not be pointed to by non-const `char *`.

Comment: Change `desc_v` to `desc` in the `for` loop

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @JamesRoot Sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had a crazy time working out in my head what was happening here.

```
  std::vector <std::string> desc_v(desc, desc + sizeof(desc)/sizeof(desc[0]));
```

You're calling the constructor of `vector desc_v` that takes two iterators and stores the values between them. It begins with the first iterator and ends just before the last one.

```
sizeof(desc)/sizeof(desc[0]) //Does not do what you intended
```

When you take `sizeof(desc)` you are taking the size of a `char**`, not an array. `sizeof(desc[0])` is the size of a `char*`, because the type of a `char**` dereferenced once is `char*`. I don't know if this is guaranteed, but at least in this case `char**` and `char*` are the same size, evaluating to `1`.

```
std::vector <std::string> desc_v(desc, desc + 1); //It turns into this
```

The range of `desc` to `desc + 1` including the first element, but not the last, is exactly `desc`. Treating it as an iterator, `desc_v` dereferences `desc` and stores the value. That value is the first element in the top layer of `desc`, which is the address of the first string literal.

That's why it only prints one sentence. To print them all, I think the closest to what you have would be to use `std::array` like M.M suggested.

Alternatively, make `opt` take a count parameter.

```
void opt(char **desc, int count)
{
    std::vector <std::string> desc_v(desc, desc + count);
    /* same */
}

//calling opt
opt(desc, 2);
```

Or if you really wanted to...

```
opt(desc, sizeof(desc) / sizeof(desc[0]));
```